# Set Sublime Text 3 as a default .txt editor on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line-interface, sublimetext3

How could I set Sublime Text 3 as a default .txt editor on Windows 10?

Here is what I tried:

1 Open `cmd.exe` as administrator.
2 Type: `ASSOC .txt=D:\Installations\Sublime\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe`

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

But I after that when I go to any .txt file and open it it still opens with a default Windows Notepad. What am I missing here? Thank you.

Here is an attempt to change the default open with app as described in the answer

```
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
[![enter image description here][5]][5]
[![enter image description here][6]][6]
```

As you can see the `.txt` file continues to open up with the default Windows Notepad.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6YNL.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9HV8.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZFmC.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVQyV.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogoHy.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMiOv.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about .txt files, simply right-click on one, select "Open with", "Choose another app", select Sublime Text in the list and then check "Always use this app to open .txt files". If you don't see Sublime Text listed, go at the bottom of the list and click on "Look for another app on this PC" and browse to the Sublime Text executable, which should be:

C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe

Reference: https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/201012-set-default-text-editor/

Okay, here is a workaround:
Create a dummy file with the extension you wish to default to your program. The file can be empty.
Right click on the dummy file and select Properties.
On the General tab there is a section that states:
Type of file: 
Opens with  and a button that says .
Click Change.
How do you want to open  files from now on? Choose .
Scroll to the bottom and select 
Go to C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe and select  and select 
Close Properties and your done!

Comment: Oh. I am sorry for not mentioning this in my question. This approach does not work for me. That is because when I try it out it changes nothing at all (I mean the .txt file is still opens up with a default Window Notepad). Thank you.

Comment: what about through Settings > Default Apps

Comment: The same for Settings > Default Apps approach. But here not only the effect of changing does not appear (i.e. the .txt file still opens up with Windows Notepad), but the app does not change when I select Sublime, it just stays the same there in Default Apps.

Comment: just reload the page now, I have updated the answer, please don't forget to accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. I solved it by using regedit.exe to remove the file-association entries related to both the application and the extension.